# Firestore security rules - possible to secure doc by array contains any value from another array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I think the answer is no, because I can't find a reference in Firestore docs:

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field)

I have an ACL setup where users are assigned to one or more user roles (access lists essentially) eg

`user.roles = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`

Each record can then also be made available to one or more user roles, also an array

`record.access.roles = [ 'c', 'd' ]`

I know I can query this on the front end using [array-contains-any](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-query#in_and_array-contains-any_queries) ... but I also need to secure the data with a similar condition returning true if any of the users roles appear the records ACL list. Currently I can only find documentation supporting an IN array condition.

In fact [this section](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-query#in_and_array-contains-any_queries) of the docs discusses the security around array-contains-any on the query side, but makes no mention if/how it's possible to secure the data this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the equivalent of array-contains-any for the purpose of determining if items in a list are present in another list, I think you will want to use [hasAny()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) on the list to check, and pass it the list of other items that should be checked for presence.

In general, I would lean on the API documentation that I linked to here, rather than the formal product documentation.  The docs you linked do no show examples of everything you can do.  The API documentation will help you understand all the functionality you have available.

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I needed. I had read that documentation before some time ago but must have forgotten it existed. Thanks so much Doug!

Comment: this actually doesn't work. Using the example posted, the security rules from the firebase console using getUser().roles.hasAny(resource.data.access.roles) DOES allow the request. But, when sending a query with array-contains-any, and an intersection of values from the user.roles[] and the resource.access.roles[], the request is denied with the standard missing permissions error - any guidance on how to filter to satisfy the permissions and get the request approved?

Comment: Without seeing complete rules matched with an actual query against actual data, it's not possible to tell what might be going wrong.  I suggest formulating a new question.